# Cases for Phidgets boards

Tags: board, cases, enclosure

Are there cases for Phidgets IO boards such as the [1019](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=0&product%5Fid=1019) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean prefabbed with bezel and all, I am not aware of any. I have used some standard project boxes for my phidget projects and they work pretty well. They just take a little work. I use a dremmel to carve the openings.